# Cannot Run Example from ReactiveMongo

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I am running reactivemongo 0.18.6 and am having an issue around the bulk Update as shown in the "Update a document" section of the documentation: http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/tutorial/write-documents.html

I copied word for word the example provided and keep getting the compilation error of

type mismatch;
found : Seq[reactivemongo.api.collections.bson.BSONCollection with Singleton#UpdateCommand.UpdateElement]
required: Iterable[_1.UpdateCommand.UpdateElement] where val _1: reactivemongo.api.collections.bson.BSONCollection

Comment: 1. The error mentioned is not a run one, but a compile one. 2. All the documentation examples are compiled before publication, so check your build and code is consistent. 3. Version 0.18 is quite (too) old.

Comment: @cchantep I am getting this currently using 0.20.13

Comment: The latest version is 1.0.x

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, using reactivemongo 1.1.0-RC9.  I was able to fix it by moving the UpdateBuilder out of a for comprehension...although I have no idea why that made a difference.

I started with the example code from the reactivemongo documentation: http://reactivemongo.org/releases/1.0/documentation/tutorial/write-documents.html

I'll copy/paste the example code directly from the documentation, in case it changes in the future:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

import reactivemongo.api.bson.BSONDocument

import reactivemongo.api.bson.collection.BSONCollection

def update1(personColl: BSONCollection) = {
  val selector = BSONDocument("name" -> "Jack")

  val modifier = BSONDocument(
    "$set" -> BSONDocument(
      "lastName" -> "London",
      "firstName" -> "Jack"),
      "$unset" -> BSONDocument("name" -> 1))

  // Simple update: get a future update
  val futureUpdate1 = personColl.update.one(
    q = selector, u = modifier,
    upsert = false, multi = false)

  // Bulk update: multiple update
  val updateBuilder1 = personColl.update(ordered = true)
  val updates = Future.sequence(Seq(
    updateBuilder1.element(
      q = BSONDocument("firstName" -> "Jane", "lastName" -> "Doh"),
      u = BSONDocument("age" -> 18),
      upsert = true,
      multi = false),
    updateBuilder1.element(
      q = BSONDocument("firstName" -> "Bob"),
      u = BSONDocument("age" -> 19),
      upsert = false,
      multi = true)))

  val bulkUpdateRes1 = updates.flatMap { ops => updateBuilder1.many(ops) }
}
```

When I copied that directly into my project, it compiled successfully.

I then started moving some of the code into a for comprehension.  I started with the BSONCollection, and that also compiled successfully:

```
private def testing(personColl: Future[BSONCollection]) = {
  for {
    collection <- personColl
  } yield {
    val updateBuilder1 = collection.update(ordered = true)
    val updates = Future.sequence(Seq(
      updateBuilder1.element(
        q = BSONDocument("firstName" -> "Jane", "lastName" -> "Doh"),
        u = BSONDocument("age" -> 18),
        upsert = true,
        multi = false),
      updateBuilder1.element(
        q = BSONDocument("firstName" -> "Bob"),
        u = BSONDocument("age" -> 19),
        upsert = false,
        multi = true)))

    val bulkUpdateRes1 = updates.flatMap { ops => updateBuilder1.many(ops) }
  }
}
```

I then made one more change: I moved the UpdateBuilder into the for comprehension.  When I did that, it failed to compile:

```
private def testing(personColl: Future[BSONCollection]) = {
  for {
    collection <- personColl
    updateBuilder1 = collection.update(ordered = true)
  } yield {
    val updates = Future.sequence(Seq(
      updateBuilder1.element(
        q = BSONDocument("firstName" -> "Jane", "lastName" -> "Doh"),
        u = BSONDocument("age" -> 18),
        upsert = true,
        multi = false),
      updateBuilder1.element(
        q = BSONDocument("firstName" -> "Bob"),
        u = BSONDocument("age" -> 19),
        upsert = false,
        multi = true)))

    val bulkUpdateRes1 = updates.flatMap { ops => updateBuilder1.many(ops) }
  }
}
```

Here is the compilation error:

```
[my_project] $ compile  
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/greg/IdeaProjects/predictive_betting/target/scala-2.12/classes...  
[error] /home/greg/IdeaProjects/predictive_betting/app/db/mongo/base/ReactiveMongoClient.scala:157: type mismatch;  
[error]  found   : Seq[reactivemongo.api.bson.collection.BSONCollection#UpdateElement]  
[error]     (which expands to)  Seq[reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericCollection[reactivemongo.api.bson.collection.BSONSerializationPack.type] with reactivemongo.api.CollectionMetaCommands#UpdateElement]  
[error]  required: Iterable[_1.UpdateElement] where val _1: reactivemongo.api.bson.collection.BSONCollection  
[error]       val bulkUpdateRes1 = updates.flatMap { ops => updateBuilder1.many(ops) }  
[error]                                                                         ^  
[error] one error found  
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed  
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 20, 2024 10:54:49 AM
```

Again, I have no idea why this made a difference, but maybe it will help someone.  Or maybe someone can explain why it made a difference.